# Does Sproutback Trudge's cost reduction get applied when we cast it from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Sproutback Trudge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sproutback%20Trudge) is a 9-mana costing card that costs 1 less for each life you gained that turn. It can also be cast (at the beginning of the end step) from the graveyard when the owner gained life that turn. So, when [Sproutback Trudge] is in the graveyard and the owner gains life on their turn, can they cast it from the graveyard in addition to it being discounted for each life gained that turn?  For instance, can one cast this card from the graveyard for just the two green mana if the owner gained 7 life that turn?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you can get both benefits in the same turn and from whatever zone you cast it.**

Sproutback Trudge's first ability applies the mana cost reduction whenever you cast it. Since it makes no limitation otherwise, it does not matter when or from which zone you cast the creature.